# How to achieve multiple tables left join in Entity Framework with proper json response

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, join

I am trying to join the 3 tables using Entity Framework LINQ statement.

This is my database diagram:

[image]

Data in `DeviceTypeGroups` table:

```
  Key         | Name
  ------------+------------------- 
  111             GroupOne
  112             GroupTwo
```

Data in `DeviceTypes` table:

```
  Key         | Name         | DeviceTypeGroupKey
  ------------+--------------+--------------------
  1             Type1          111
  2             Type2          111
  3             Type3          112
```

Data in `Peers` table:

```
  Key         | Name         | DeviceTypeGroupKey
  ------------+--------------+---------------------
  1             Peer1          111
  2             Peer2          112
  3             Peer3          112
```

I want to get an output like this:

[image]

Here is the LINQ code and C# web API method I am trying

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("devicetypegroups")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetDeviceTypeGroups")]
    [SwaggerResponse(400, "Bad input parameter")]
    [SwaggerResponse(404, "Not found")]
    [SwaggerResponse(500, "Internal server error")]
    public virtual IActionResult GetDeviceTypeGroups()
    {
        try
        {
            var devicetypegroups = 
                (from dtg in _context.DeviceTypeGroups join dt in _context.DeviceTypes 
                 on dtg.Key equals dt.DeviceTypeGroup.Key into dtgleft from dtgrecs in dtgleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join pr in _context.Peers on dtgrecs.Key equals pr.DeviceTypeGroup.Key into peerleft
                 from peerleftRecs in peerleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { dtg.Key, dtg.Name, dtg.DeviceTypes, dtg.Peers }).ToList();
           }
       }
```

But it's not returning the proper response, it adds a few extra records:

[image]

As you see, it creates extra number of nodes which is same as device type count!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i resolved it by using `AutoMapper`

```
        var devicetypegroups = await _context.DeviceTypeGroups
                .Include(b => b.DeviceTypes)
                .Include(p => p.Peers)
                .ToListAsync();


        var model = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DeviceTypeGroupDto>>(devicetypegroups);
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like below :

```
    var details = (from dtg in _context.DeviceTypeGroups
                      join dt in _context.DeviceTypes on dtg.Key equals dt.DeviceTypeGroup.Key into dtgleft
                 from dtgrecs in dtgleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join pr in _context.Peers on dtgrecs.Key equals pr.DeviceTypeGroup.Key into peerleft 
                 from peerleftRecs in peerleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                      {
                          dtg.Key,
                          dtg.Name,
                          dtg.DeviceTypes,
                          dtg.Peers
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried, but response has extra empty nodes as updated in question. how can see what exact sql query is running behind the screen?

Comment: I think we need to use DISTINCT somewhere

Comment: DeviceTypes comes but peers is empty